# oracle query to bring the date like 2021-06-23 00:00:00.000, 2021-06-23 23:59:59.000 for current date

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

oracle query to bring the output like this
2021-06-23 00:00:00.000,

date between 2021-06-23 00:00:00.000 and 2021-06-23 23:59:59.000
current date with 0 hours 0 minutes and current date with 23 hours 59 minutes

Comment: "current date with 0 hours 0 minutes" - but you show from 2021-06-17, not 2021-06-23, so which do you need? And if the 17th, is that a fixed date, or you want 6 days ago from today? Why does the display format matter if this is for a date filter; or do you want the output formatted as well? And as you've shown fractional seconds, are these actually dates or timestamps - if they are timestamps shouldn't the range include say 23:59:59.001, which is currently excluded? Sample data (and data types) and expected results would be useful, if you can edit those into your question.

Comment: updated alex . i have written in sql server but oracle is new for me so need help

Comment: sql server script
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DD,0,GETDATE()))) + CAST(TIMEFROMPARTS(0,0,0,0,0) AS DATETIME) ,
      @EDATE  = CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())) + CAST(TIMEFROMPARTS(23,59,59,0,0) AS DATETIME)

Answer (score 1):

When looking for a range of dates (or timestamps) it's simpler and safer to use two conditions to define the start and end, rather than using `between`. So for a date column you could do:

```
where your_column >= date '2021-06-23'
and your_column < date '2021-06-24'
```

and for a timestamp column you could do:

```
where your_column >= timestamp '2021-06-23 00:00:00'
and your_column < timestamp '2021-06-24 00:00:00'
```

though both would work for either data type.

To base it on today - and you would need to choose between sysdate and current_date - you could use [`trunc()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html) to get midnight today, and add a day to that to get the upper bound:

```
where your_column >= trunc(sysdate)
and your_column < trunc(sysdate) + 1
```

or

```
where your_column >= trunc(sysdate)
and your_column < trunc(sysdate) + interval '1' day
```

optionally explicitly casting those to timestamps.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dd1091c4b4c0d8365527092e42514367) with dates.
[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=647e18840aca751ec3ccb456baef2f4b) with timestamps.

---

The reason I think it's safer is that you could do:

```
where your_column between timestamp '2021-06-23 00:00:00'
                      and timestamp '2021-06-23 23:59:59'
```

but if it turned out that your column was a timestamp and has values like `2021-06-23 23:59:59.123` then those would be excluded - because the .123 fractional seconds puts the value after the upper bound, when you would might have been expecting it to be included in that day's range.

[db<.fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8c97f0274aa6d62bb0cabe31a39fe41b)

---

To display the query results in a particular format you can either set your session NLS settings, as I did in the db<>fiddle demos, which your client can then use to display the native date/timestamp datatype values - though some clients have their own settings, and an application will have its own handling; or to get a string value you can explicitly convert:

```
select to_char(your_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') as result
from ...
```

Note that the `FF` [format model](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-49B32A81-0904-433E-B7FE-51606672183A) is only valid for timestamps.